# Shower Runs out of hot water after a few minutes but sinks stay hot at the same time

Tags: plumbing, shower, hot-water, tankless

I've just moved into a new house and my shower runs out of hot water after a few minutes.

It's heated by a 10 year old Bosch tankless natural gas unit which I believe claims 105k output BTU which should easily be enough to handle the shower.

One interesting thing I noted is that I get more hot water if I leave my two bathroom faucets on on full the entire time. The interesting thing is that if I leave these on, when I get out of the shower once it has turned cold, the sinks will still be medium sometimes very hot.

I did a descaling flush on my tankless unit and I did not see any scale coming out in the flush.

Interested to get thoughts.

Comment: I wonder if you might have a hot water mixing valve that is out of whack

Comment: Do you have a recirculation pump?

Comment: @TonySmith no, I do not have a recirculation pump

Comment: I'm getting to be less and less of a fan of tankless water heaters. I have one at a vacation home and the shower will suddenly go cold and then warm up again. I think it's cycling on and off.  In your case, leaving the sink tap on, increases the flow rate so it's not cycling as much, if at all.  That's just speculation on my part, hopefully others will weigh in and educate us all!  I also agree with z4-tier that you may have a mixing valve problem, those cartridges do wear out and fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the unit and I now get hot water. I think the old unit was simply not able to consistently provide hot water any more